# Border bottom animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

How can I make the bottom border animations like [here](http://htmlcoder.me/preview/the_project/v.1.1/template/index-construction.html) ? In main header.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not a border-bottom and it surely isn't attached to the main header at all. It's a timer for when the carousel slides to the next image.

Anyway, to achieve that sort of animation you can use CSS3.

HTML:

```
<div class="timer-wrapper">
  <div class="timer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.timer-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
}

.timer {
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  animation: timerAnimation 5s ease;
}

@keyframes timerAnimation {
  from { }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/zgy9m9o3/)